# How to extend a list in java to store additional metadata and force it to accept only one type of objects?

Tags: java, list, collections, extending

In addition to the included items, I have to store the name and the id of the List inside itself. Thus i extended an `ArrayList` as follows:

```
class MyList<E> extends ArrayList<E>{
    private int id;
    private String name;

    MyList(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    id getId(){       return id;   }
    String getName(){ return name; }
}
```

Now I realized, that this extension will only hold one specific type of objects. So how can I remove the generic character of my list?

```
class MyList<MyObject> extends ArrayList<E>
class MyList<MyObject> extends ArrayList<MyObject>
```

...and so on fails. I want to instantiate my list by

```
MyList mylist = new MyList();
```

...and it should automatically accept only `MyObject`s...

(Would it be better to create a wrapper which holds an `ArrayList` in addition to the meta? But because it is still a list, why remove all list-typical capabilities...)

Comment: I think this is a case where composition should be used instead of inheritance.  Create your class and have `ArrayList` as one of its class variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need

```
class MyList extends ArrayList<MyObject>
```

When you declare a type parameter for your class declaration like so

```
class MyList<MyObject> ...
```

the type `MyObject>` is not your type, it is a type variable that also has the name `MyObject`.

What you want, is to use your `MyObject` type as a type argument for the `ArrayList` type parameter as shown above.

---

But, as others have suggested, composition is probably a better way to do this, ie the wrapper you suggested in your question.

Answer (score 2):

As has been answered already, the correct declaration would be

```
class MyList extends ArrayList<MyObject>
```

Even though you have no interest in overriding any `ArrayList` methods, you should consider composition over inheritance for this type of scenarios.

Example:

```
class MyList implements Iterable<MyObject> {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    private final List<MyObject> list;

    MyList(int id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    int getId()                     { return id; }

    String getName()                { return name; }

    MyObject get(int i)             { return list.get(i); }

    void add(MyObject o)            { list.add(o); }

    void remove(MyObject o)         { list.remove(o); }

    void remove(int i)              { list.remove(i); }

    void set(int i, MyObject o)     { list.set(i, o); }

    boolean contains(MyObject o)    { return list.contains(o); }

    int size()                      { return list.size(); }

    @Override
    Iterator<MyObject> iterator()   { return list.iterator(); }
}
```

With this:

- You can easily switch the `ArrayList` for a `LinkedList`, or any other list;
- You control the methods this class offers;
- If you like the *chaining* style, you may change those `void` for `MyList`;
- *etc*.

Comment: Thank you for this example. One question just to understand: Why didn't you implement the `List<E>` interface? It is still a list and when I want to iterate through it etc. this where still possible. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @nico411 For sure this class can implement `List<MyObject>`, but it doesn't, just to show that you don't have to, it's optional. You have the liberty to decide what's more convenient to you. For instance, if you want to implement *chaining* (e.g. `list.add(e1).add(e2).add(e3)`), you won't be able to implement `List`. As to iteration, you just have to implement `Iterable`. I've updated my answer to illustrate it.